# What calculations are used for cleaning subs sea pipelines with detergents

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Main issue here is to calculate the most efficient number of pills for pumping to clean a crude pipeline with detergents in water. Normally I use 200bbls +/- 500ft for vertical pipes but 40 km horizontal pipelines may be different.Also the 1st pill is usually a very thick gel pill and then followed by detergent pills. Retention time should be 5-10 mins . With the detergent pills 200 bbls at 8 bbls /min converts to a RT of round 25 mins in a 12" pipeline which is more than adequate. I'm interested in calculating the optimum number of pills with spacers in this pipeline. There many be different sizes of pipes to also content with (20") and would be interested to see what length of these different sizes of pipe change the optimised number of pills.Not exactly sure how I should approach this seemingly simple question or which calcualtions to use.

Comment: This sounds more like a chemical engineering problem.